# Spring Boot audit @Query

Tags: spring-boot, audit

It's possible to user Spring boot Audit with JPA @Query annotation?
For example i have the next Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update Item i set statusId = :statusId WHERE i.id = :id")
    void updateById(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("statusId") Long statusId);
}
```

But when i use this into my service it's not updating update_date column in database:

```
@Autowired
private ItemRepository itemRepository;

@Transactional
public void updateItemStatus(Long itemId, Long statusId) {
    //Case 1: This is working, update_date column is updated
    Item item = itemRepository.findById(itemId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Item", "id", itemId));
    item.setStatusId(statusId);
    itemRepository.save(item);

    //Case 2: This is not working
    itemRepository.updateById(itemId, statusId);

}
```

So, can i use Audit with @Query annotation ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Auditing is based on the JPA Lifecycle events. Only the methods directly manipulating instances (persist, merge and remove) trigger such events.

The execution of queries, modifying or otherwise, does not trigger any events and therefore, won't cause auditing to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax issue

Either use

```
@Query(value = "update Item i set i.statusId = :statusId WHERE i.id = :id")
```

or

```
@Query(value = "update Item set statusId = :statusId WHERE id = :id")
```